# Show that the solution space does not make up a sub space

Tags: linear-algebra

We are given the following equation:
$${x_1} - 3{x_2} + 2{x_3} + 4{x_4} = 1$$

The aim is to show that the *solution space* of this equation does not create a subspace for $\mathbb{R^4}$.

**My reasoning**

The first thing I did was to figure out the vector representation of the solution space, by letting $x_2=s,x_3=t,x_3=u$. That is,

$$({x_1},{x_2},{x_3},{x_4}) = s(3,1,0,0) + t( - 2,0,1,0) + u( - 4,0,0,1) + (1,0,0,0)$$

Now, we know that the following conditions can be checked to find out whether something is a subspace.

- $u,v\in W \implies (u+v)\in W$
- $k\in \mathbb{R},u\in W \implies ku\in W$.

The second condition says that $W$ should contain a zero vector ($k=0$). So, my next step is to check whether the zero vector $(0,0,0,0)$ is a part of $W$. This is achieved by solving the systems of equations below:

$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
3&{ - 2}&{ - 4}&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0
\end{array}} \right)\ \sim el.row.op.\sim \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0
\end{array}} \right)$$

Based on this result, we have infinity many solutions, one is for example 
$$s=t=u=0$$

By setting $s,t,u$ to zero into the vector representation of the solution space above,
we get $(1,0,0,0).$ It seems to be a contradiction, and that we cannot express a zero vector in the solution space, thus it's not a subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$.
Does this seem to be correct?

EDIT: The matrix above should have 5 columns, where the last one is 0.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of work! It's easier to observe that $0-3(0)+2(0)+4(0)\neq1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you see that this ''space'' don't pass through the origin because $(0,0,0,0)$ don't verifies the equation. So it cannot be a subspace.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! +1